# Apple Configurator 2 won't save changes to home screen layout

Tags: iphone, apple-configurator

iPhone 8 Plus, iOS 13.1

Despite applying the changes in the Home Screen Layout menu, the changes do not appear to take on the device itself. When I open the menu again to change the layout it simply never made the changes and reverts back to how the phone is when it's plugged in.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Update 9/27/19: I spoke with Apple support and they elevated it to the engineering team. They replicated it, could not get it to save the changes either, so they logged a report and noted it. If enough people have the issue then I suppose a fix will come. But in the meantime, it appears to be a bug.

Comment: I have the same problem. iphone 8, IOS 13.1.2. I can adjust layout in AC2 and apply it. But it doesn't take effect on connected iphone, and when I update again it's the original layout. Oh how I missed the itunes version for editing app layout!

Comment: Still an issue in Configurator 2.1b6

Comment: Using Configurator 2.7.1, still doesn't work.

Comment: Using 2.11.1 and it still won't save - @hwp08 do you have a bug report number?

Comment: I just tried it on a device still on iOS 12 - and that woks fine. So this is obviously an issue with iOS 13

Comment: Hi Jeff, no I don't have a bug report number.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Apple Configurator 2 version 2.13.3 (5B55) and the "Apply" button does apply the changes to my iPhone 6 (running iOS 14.4.2).

Unfortunately, the modal dialog doesn't have a scroll bar, so it only allows me to change app icons from the first 4 home screens. I have enough icons to fill 7 screens on my phone but the final ones are not available.