# How can I modify the Home Screen layout from macOS?

Tags: ios, apple-configurator

Apple Configurator 2 can [allegedly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/370984/4395) be used to modify the Home Screen layout on an iOS device from macOS. However it appears to provide no way to configure the major new feature of Home Screens: Widgets. As near as I can tell Configurator 2 just supports reordering and regrouping of apps.

Can Configurator 2 in fact be used to modify the Home Screen (Widgets included)? If not is there a tool that can?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, the answer appears still to be "No".

In fact, even moving the icons around is now unreliable - for some it does not work, for others any widgets are completely removed as a result of doing so.